# Relationship Direction can't be retained after using call apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using neo4j community edition 3.0.6 and apoc 3.0.8.6.
I'm having this issues where i tried to copy a node that already have multiple relationship.
Then when I use call apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships([node1,node2,…​]) the nodes and its relationship are copied.
But the relationship direction is wrong.
Attached the image below. As You can see in the image the relationship direction between A-B is wrong. Like it seems all the relationship created there is considered as outgoing relationship.
Is this a bug on apoc 3.0.8.6 or is there any solution regarding this issue ?

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update about this issue. Sorry but just found out it was my query fault.
I did use a query like this.

```
MATCH (p:A)-[r1:A_has_B]->(l:B) 
WHERE p.id IN {0} WITH COLLECT(l) as oldBList 
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships(oldBList) YIELD output 
CALL apoc.create.uuid() YIELD uuid SET output.id = uuid 
WITH COLLECT(output.id) as copiedIds
MATCH (l2:B)-[r1]-() 
WHERE l2.id IN copiedIdsAND r1.id IS NOT NULL 
CALL apoc.create.uuid() YIELD uuid 
SET r1.id = uuid 
WITH copiedIds as copiedIds
UNWIND(copiedIds) as result
RETURN result
```

Apparently I have a case where there isn't any relationship with B that have r.id therefore the copiedIds somehow not returned to the result query. Making it seems like transactional problem.

Thanks for all the helps

Answer (score 0):

I see that you created APOC [issue #936](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/936) for this, which appears to be a duplicate of [issue #229](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/2299).

I have added [a comment](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/229#issuecomment-426462280) to issue #229 with my analysis of the APOC bug.

Comment: Hi, I just saw the issue that You referenced. It seems the problem is different. My problem is the direction is wrong. Meanwhile the issue #229 problem is the relationship not copied correctly.

Comment: There are new relationships going in the wrong direction in both issues. There is a very strong possibility they are caused by the same bug.

Comment: Hmm so currently its still not fixed yet ? Or is there any other solution ?
Right now I'm inverting the wrongly created relationship direction manually.